# can we increase the size of embedded google presentation?

Tags: embedding, google-docs

I am embedding google presentation in my website. But the slides in it are very small and hard to view. Is there some way by I which I could increase the display area of that embedded google presentation. Or, it can't be done at all and I should not waste time searching for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this your document? If so just go into google docs and re-publish the presentation, but choose the large player size.

If it's not your presentation (you don't have access to the presentation in google docs) you can tweak the html:

Here's the markup for the (default) small player:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/present/embed?id=<your_document_id>" frameborder="0" width="410" height="342"></iframe>
```

And here's the markup for the (default) large player:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/present/embed?id=<your_document_id>&size=l" frameborder="0" width="700" height="559"></iframe>
```

Comment: Looks like a useful answer. However there seem to be a few stray characters and inconsistent quotation marks in those markup samples.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! your code for default large player worked for me. 
Can we tell me one more thing.. that I haven't published my document and used document's id to embed it.. would this document appear in google searches or crawled by google??
thanks again.

Comment: "a few stray characters and inconsistent quotation marks in those markup samples"? Where?

Comment: I've had another look. Actually quotation marks look okay. Is the "aj" before "<your_document_id>" in the first markup meant to be there?